# unable to load csv to d3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I tried multiple tutorials and looked into prior questions yet still have issue loading csv to d3, as all of materials use a different methods.

The dataset xyz.csv looks like this

```
xvalue,yvalue
30,20
50,30
70,10
```

And here's the code that won't work after trying for hours:

the first chunk:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> function draw(data) {


    var margin = 50,
        width = 700,
        height = 300,
        x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.xvalue}),
        y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.yvalue});

    var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([margin,width-margin])
        .domain(x_extent)

    var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height-margin, margin])
        .domain(y_extent)

    var x_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x_scale)
    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y_scale).orient('left')


    d3.select("body")
      .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d){return x_scale(d.xvalue)})
        .attr('cy', function(d){return y_scale(d.yvalue)})
        .attr('r', 5)


}
    </script>
```

Then

```
<body>
 <script>
     d3.csv('xyz.csv', draw);
 </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

What are some of the easy ways to bind csv for beginners? thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me, is there an error message?

Comment: @AndrewReid it's just blank where the chart is supposed to be. i have an example code with json binding in the same folder and that works fine, but not this one

Comment: Hmm, [here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/e7da5614c8b3409e01398bcff5a1b5c9) is your code (showing the circles based on coordinates that are in the csv), the only way I don't get it to work is if I place the function in separate script tags below the tag with `d3.csv()`.

Comment: indeed. i couldn't explain why it doesn't work on http://localhost:8000 but thanks for pointing to bl.ockbuilder!

Comment: @santoku you probably are not using a server. Browsers don't allow loading local files.

Comment: I used python -m http.server and added some text to the page which shows. Let me try v4 and see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This depends slightly on which version of d3 you are using. [d3 v5](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) uses the fetch API and returns a promise requiring the below code.

```js
d3.csv('yourcsv.csv')
  .then(function(data) {
      // data is now whole data set
      // draw chart in here!
  })
```

[d3 v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) on the other hand uses the xmlhttp method and does not return a promise requiring this code

```js
d3.csv('yourcsv.csv', function(data) {
    //whole data set
    // draw chart here
})
```

csv loading is async so make sure to run your chart code within the csv function.

Comment: thanks @pmkro. i'm using v4. after moving the 1st chunk into d3.csv('yourcsv.csv', function(data) {
    //whole data set
    // draw chart here
})  it still doesn't show anything, is that i need to somehow parse csv value into numbers?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately everything gets loaded in as strings. Can just iterate through the array and coerce what needs to be.

Comment: so I added these data.forEach(function(d) {
        xyz.xvalue = +xyz.xvalue;
        xyz.yvalue = +xyz.yvalue;
     }); before the //draw chart here. shows nothing. something missing? thanks

Comment: If you are using v4, your code is in v3. This might cause an issue. Axis are defined differently in v4.

Comment: thank you. i realised this particular code is using v3. is there a good way to find learning material/tutorial only in one particular version?

Comment: I usually just search, I find the APIs good for me [d3 v3 API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md)